# Getting Postgis/JDBC to work with BoneCP in Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, postgis

So I'm using BoneCP and creating my datasource in Spring:

```
<bean id="baseDataSource" abstract="true" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClass" value="#{T(io.bigsense.spring.MySpring).dbDriver('${dbms}')}" />
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{T(io.bigsense.spring.MySpring).dbConnectionString('${dbms}','${dbHostname}','${dbDatabase}','${dbPort}')}" />
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${dbPoolMaxPerPart}"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${dbPoolMinPerPart}"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="${dbPoolPartitions}"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
   <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>
```

Most of those values come from a property file. In this particular case, the `driverClass` is `org.postgresql.Driver` and my `jdbcUrl` is `jdbc:postgresql://[hostname]:[port]/[database]` returned from some custom functions.

I have postgis installed on my postgres-9.4 instance and I've found documentation that states that in order to send Geography objects to Postgres via JDBC, you need to add the data types to the connection:

```
import java.sql.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import org.postgis.*; 

...
  java.sql.Connection conn; 

  try { 
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database"; 
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "postgres", ""); 
    ((org.postgresql.Connection)conn).addDataType("geometry","org.postgis.PGgeometry")
;   ((org.postgresql.Connection)conn).addDataType("box3d","org.postgis.PGbox3d");
```

My question is, how do I do this with my BoneCP setup? If I do a `getConnection()` from my BoneCP data source, I can't case it to a `org.postgresql.PGConnection` because its type is actually that of `com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle`.

How do I setup PostGIS datatypes with the underlying Postgres drivers when using a BoneCP data source defined in a Spring application context?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer. I need to use the postgis `DriverWrapper` class: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/DriverWrapper.html